# Alternar menu registro login usuario vs cierre de sesion

Tags: php, wordpress, login

Tras realizar varias búsquedas con Google, no he conseguido encontrar un aspecto funcional que me haría falta sobre el proceso de registro/login de usuario en la web (Wordpress) que estoy desarrollando. A continuación indico los pasos realizados hasta ahora y mi necesidad:

1.En el fichero function.php del tema hijo he registrado el siguiente código para incluir una nueva ubicación para un menú, donde aparecerá un link  a la página que contiene el formulario de Registro/Login del usuario en la web:

```
<?php
register_nav_menus( array(
'login' => esc_html__( 'Login', 'music' ),
) );
?>
```

2. En el fichero “header.php”, llamamos a este menú de Registro/Login creado:

   ```
   if ( has_nav_menu( 'login' ) ) {
   echo '<div class="login-nav">';
   $login_menu_args = array(
   'theme_location'  => 'login',
   'container'       => 'ul',
   'menu_class'      => 'nolmp',
   'echo'            => true,
   'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
   );
   wp_nav_menu( $login_menu_args );
   echo '</div>';
   }
   ```

3.He instalado el plugin “ultimatemember” y, en el proceso de instalación, se crean páginas asociadas al proceso de registro del usuario ("entrar", "cerrar sesión", "reestablecer contraseña") que, a su vez, aparecen en Apariencia>Menú del escritorio de Wordpress. Incluyo la página "entrar" en el menú creado en el paso anterior.

4. Cuando el usuario hace clic en el menú "entrar" y se loguea  (en el caso de registro le llega un mail para verificar su cuenta), lo que me gustaría es que desapareciera en el menú el link a la página de “entrar” y se cambiara automáticamente por el de “cerrar sesión”, esto es, haciendo clic en un icono (por ejemplo de www.fontawesome.com), que se pudiera desconectar y, cuando ya esté desconectado, que apareciera nuevamente el link a la página "entrar"

**¿cómo sería el código a incluir?**

Muchas gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os indico la respuesta a la cuestión que planteaba:

```
<?php 
if(is_user_logged_in()) {

    echo $items = '<li class="right"><a href="'. 
wp_login_url(get_permalink()) .'">'. __("Log Out") .'</a></li>';
}
else {
   echo '<div class="login-nav">';
    $login_menu_args = array(
    'theme_location'  => 'login',
    'container'       => 'ul',
    'menu_class'      => 'nolmp',
    'echo'            => true,
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    );
    wp_nav_menu( $login_menu_args );
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Special thanks for this response to:
@Vel
@Pike Milsner